# Make Sails.js listen on unix socket file instead on port?

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

How do I make Sails.js listen on unix socket file instead of network port? It looks like Express.js [supports](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_path_callback) this functionality.